# Re-run build script whenever code changes

Tags: reactjs, express, webpack, package.json

So in my codebase I have a `server.js` file which is an `express` app that serves the `index.html` of `dist` folder.

I also have a build script which is a webpack script to build a react application which looks something like this
`webpack --mode=development --out-dir dist`

The issue is I have to do `npm run build` and then do `node server.js` each time I change something in the code to see my latest changes.

I want to enable **hot reloading.**

I tried to install [watch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/watch) package.
and include a script in `package.json` but that does not work unfortunately.

```json
scripts: {
 "watch":"watch 'npm run build' ./dist"
}
```

> I know If I could create a build everytime code changes I can listen to server using nodemon, but I am unsure as to how I could achieve it.

**And better way to do this ??**

Comment: `nodemon` for the backend server, `webpack --watch` for the frontend.

Comment: It'll be quite some work to configure Webpack for hot reloading, though, but good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I added a watch build script and which updates my dist folder whenever the code changes happens.

```json
scripts: {
"build-watch": "webpack --mode=development --out-dir dist --watch"
}
```

After this I run a `nodemon server.js` so that my new changes in dist folder are picked by express server and served locally.